# wanting to know the equations for calculating the output of a generator that has a static input

Tags: generator, output, static, variable

There is a variable speed generator that is 100% efficient. It has a 2 ft. diameter pulley attached to its shaft. There is 100 ft. of cable attached to the pulley and a 1000 lb. "static" force attached to the cable. The cable is allowed to turn the pulley at any speed and the generator will produce electrical current at any speed. What is the maximum output in watts that can be achieved? Am really interested to know the equations and reasoning for an accurate answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "static" force?

Comment: I suggest you reformat the question using lower case letter. As it is it is not pleasing to the eye. I changes a few, but it is your question so it is best that you make the changes

Comment: This is really a physics problem, not electrical engineering. The generator will convert all of the mechanical energy that the mechanical system can produce at the rate that it can be produced. It a constant force unwinds 1000 feet of cable that is entirely wound up on a pulley, that is 1000 ft.-lbs. of energy. A watt is a rate of energy production like ft.-lbs per. second. To calculate watts, you need to determine what might determine or limit the time of action. If there is no limit on the speed, the time is zero and the power is infinite.

Comment: 100% efficient???

Answer (score 1):

Power is defined as Volts multiplied by Amps... but did you know that Newton-Meters per second is also a unit of power? Nm is a torque (a 1N force on the end of a 1m bar is 1Nm, you can work out the rest), now the rate of *power* generating capacity will be dependent on how fast that big ol' weight moves.

A weight some height above ground has potential *energy* (mass*gravity*height, now mass*gravity = weight in Newtons... funny eh?), when that energy is expended over some time period we can start talking in units of power (1 watt is 1 Joule being used in 1 second).

If the weight starts falling down from a standstill you can work out the speed (it'll be accelerating), but if there's a load on the generator, it'll generate a retarding torque in the generator that generates a force down the cable on the weight that opposes gravity so the power generated will be exactly the amount needed to keep the weight falling at a constant speed.

(hint: notice how there's no requirement as to *what* that constant speed should be, that depends on the load that's *using* the power). Play around with the equations a bit (but KEEP the units in the equations, they'll tell you if you've made a mistake somewhere).

g = 9.8m/s^s, m = mass in kg, h = height in meters, E = Nm = mgh = mg*(pulley radius in meters) = energy in Joules. t = time in seconds. P = Nm/s = V*I = E/t.
Notice how the Power (E/t) is dependent only on how fast the weight moves from top to bottom (mgh/t or gravity * distance * speed = gh * m/s) and is not affected by the pulley at all?